# Instagram Like Notification Page

Tags: flutter, notifications

I have made a notification page which looks like Instagram and its working perfectly fine.But i want to add one thing, for notifications less than 24 hours, i want to show a text "Today" above that and more than 24 hours, i want to show a text "Older Notifications". I am not able to achieve this. Please help me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:masalabox_flutter/app/modules/user_profile/controller/ctr_profile.dart';
import 'package:masalabox_flutter/app/themes_styles/colors.dart';
import 'package:masalabox_flutter/app/themes_styles/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:masalabox_flutter/app/utilities/utils_class.dart';

    class UINotification extends GetView<CtrProfile> {
    const UINotification({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.secondaryBackgroundColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text("Notifications", style: Styles.clickableText),
          leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Get.back(),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: false,
        ),
        body: Obx(
          () => controller.isLoading.value
              ? Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/gifs/loader.gif',
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
                )
              : controller.notification.isNotEmpty
                  ? Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              reverse: true,
                              itemCount: controller.notification.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                DateTime notificationDate =
                                    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                        controller.notification[index].ts!
                                                .toInt() *
                                            1000);

                                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
                                if (notificationDate.year == currentDate.year &&
                                    notificationDate.month ==
                                        currentDate.month &&
                                    notificationDate.day == currentDate.day) {
                                  if (index == 0) {
                                    return Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 17, left: 20),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Today',
                                            style: Styles.lineTextMedium
                                                .copyWith(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w600),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        notificationItem(
                                            index,
                                            controller.profileImageUrl.value,
                                            (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                            ?.type ??
                                                        "") ==
                                                    "USER"
                                                ? (controller
                                                        .notification[index]
                                                        ?.p
                                                        ?.param ??
                                                    "")
                                                : " "),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return notificationItem(
                                        index,
                                        controller.profileImageUrl.value,
                                        (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                        ?.type ??
                                                    "") ==
                                                "USER"
                                            ? (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                    ?.param ??
                                                "")
                                            : " ");
                                  }
                                } else if (notificationDate.year ==
                                        currentDate.year &&
                                    notificationDate.month ==
                                        currentDate.month &&
                                    notificationDate.day ==
                                        currentDate.day - 1) {
                                  if (index == 0) {
                                    return Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 17, left: 20),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Yesterday',
                                            style: Styles.lineTextMedium
                                                .copyWith(
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.w600),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        notificationItem(
                                            index,
                                            controller.profileImageUrl.value,
                                            (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                            ?.type ??
                                                        "") ==
                                                    "USER"
                                                ? (controller
                                                        .notification[index]
                                                        ?.p
                                                        ?.param ??
                                                    "")
                                                : " "),
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }
                                  // Otherwise, show the notification without any label
                                  else {
                                    return notificationItem(
                                        index,
                                        controller.profileImageUrl.value,
                                        (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                        ?.type ??
                                                    "") ==
                                                "USER"
                                            ? (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                    ?.param ??
                                                "")
                                            : " ");
                                  }
                                }
                                // Otherwise, show the notification without any label
                                else {
                                  return notificationItem(
                                      index,
                                      controller.profileImageUrl.value,
                                      (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                      ?.type ??
                                                  "") ==
                                              "USER"
                                          ? (controller.notification[index]?.p
                                                  ?.param ??
                                              "")
                                          : " ");
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                 
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'No New Notification',
                        style: Styles.valueText,
                      ),
                    ),
        ));
  }

  notificationItem(
      dynamic notification, String profileImageUrl, String userHandle) {
    String hash = Utils.getHash(userHandle);

    DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        controller.notification[notification].ts!.toInt() * 1000);

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          CachedNetworkImage(
            width: 46,
            height: 46,
            imageUrl: profileImageUrl +
                'users/' +
                userHandle +
                '_' +
                hash +
                '_profile.jpg',
            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //   placeholder: (context, url) => buildShimmerPlaceholder(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/pro_icon.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: Get.width * 0.7,
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(children: [
                      TextSpan(
                          text: controller.notification[notification].t,
                          style: Styles.clickableTextMedium),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 3,
              ),
              Text(
                "${controller.getNotificationTime(controller.notification[notification].ts!).toString()}  ago",
                style: Styles.searchTextGrey,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide your notifications by this logic to `notificationForToday` and `notificationForOlder` like this:

```
List<Notifications> notificationForToday = [];
    List<Notifications> notificationForOlder = [];
    //DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    DateTime yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));

    for (Notifications i in controller.notification) {
      DateTime notificationDate =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(i.ts!.toInt());
      int differenceInHour = yesterday.difference(notificationDate).inHours;
      // print("titleofNotification : ${i.t} differenceinhour $differenceInHour");
      //print("yesterday : $yesterday : notifictiondate : $notificationDate");

      if (differenceInHour.isNegative || differenceInHour == 0) {
        notificationForToday.add(i);
      } else {
        notificationForOlder.add(i);
      }
 }
```

if the `differenceInHour` from the differences between `notificationDate` and `yesterday` is negative or is zero the item goes to `notificationForToday` and in the else it goes to `notificationForOlder`.

happy coding...

Comment: hi, i have applied your logic and it worked for me, thank you so much for your input, you were a great help.

Comment: Anytime bro, I'm so happy that I could help you.